# Find the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\ln( x)} {x(1-\ln (x))}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Evaluate$$\int \frac{\ln (x)}{x(1-\ln(x))}\,dx$$

Comment: substitute $u=ln(x)$. then the integral becomes $\int{\frac{u}{1-u}du}$

Comment: and the result is $$-\log (x)-\log (\log (x)-1)$$

Comment: +C @Dr.SonnhardGraubner haha

Comment: haha said the Clown, this is a song by the Kinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the substitution $u = \ln(x)$, so that $\displaystyle \,du = \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ is helpful.

This turns $\displaystyle \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x(1-\ln(x))}\,dx=\int \frac{\ln x}{1-\ln x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$ into $\displaystyle \int \frac{u}{1-u}\,du$.

That is equal to $\displaystyle \int \frac{-u}{u-1}\,du=\int \frac{-u+1-1}{u-1}\,du=\int(-1-\frac{1}{u-1})\,du$

$\displaystyle=-u-\ln(u-1)+C=\boxed{-\ln|x|-\ln|\ln(x)-1|+C}$

---

Comment: What about the case $x <e $.

Answer (score 0):

> without substitution

The integrand can be simplified as

$$\frac {\ln (x)}{x (1-\ln (x))}=\frac {1}{x (1-\ln (x))}-\frac {1}{x} $$

$$=-\frac {\frac {-1}{x}}{1-\ln (x)}-\frac {1}{x} $$
the integral is

$$-\ln\Bigl (|1-\ln (x)|\Bigr)-\ln (x)+C=$$

$$\boxed {C-\ln\Bigl(| x (1-\ln (x)) |\Bigr)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x \ln x - x) = \frac{x}{x} + \ln x - 1= \ln x$$
thus we have a case of
$$-\int\frac{f'}{f}dx = -\int \frac{1}{f} df = -\ln(f).$$

Plugging in gives: $$-\ln(f) = - \ln (x \ln(x) -x) = -\ln (x) - \ln(\ln(x)-1)$$